# How to prevent anyone sees method statements code when pressing F12?

Tags: c#, deployment, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I define a method in a class and call it in another class. It works fine.

But, if I select the method and press `F12`, Visual Studio will find the method and show me the statements code automatically.

I have tried it with the method: `Console.WriteLine();`. I select `WriteLine` and press `F12`. It redirects me to:

```
namespace System
{
   public static class Console
   {
      public static void WriteLine();
   }
}
```

All of the statements code of `WriteLine()` are hidden (sorry, `hidden` means that I don't see it).

I want to write a new method like `WriteLine()`:

```
public int Add(int a, int b);
```

But I don't know where is the place I can implement method `Add(int a, int b)` (in another class).

Can you teach me?

Comment: The answer below was exactly my thoughts and works well. You could try "method hiding with inheritance"

Comment: The question makes no sense. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? You can't disable IDE functionality from source code, nor should you want to. Disabling the "Go To" button makes absolutely no sense - anyone can still read the source code, search for the definitions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Only the compiled (dll) methods can't be shown. If you're importing a project with code source then you'll see the code (that's the purpose)

Comment: You can still view the source of a dll. ILSpy for example

Comment: Or Reflector. Or ReSharper. Or JustDecompile. Some of these tools will even allow you to debug into the decompiled code

Comment: Yes there are many tools for that. But the simple `F12` won't do it